# React Native code is not running on Emulator in VS Code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Emulator is opening fine when I try to run the code with the command in VS Code but code is not running on it. Something is wrong that I'm unable to solve. Please help!
Following is the error -

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:7884) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\OLA\OlaProject\android\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'D:\OLA\OlaProject\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'OlaProject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your `settings.gradle` and `Gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

Maybe it's problem with the gradle version you are using, try to change your gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and see if it's working or not.

Also check `build.gradle` and see if `com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x` is compatible with your current gradle version

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: I have updated the details. I know the current gradle5 version is not compatible with Java16 version in new project. But updating them will result errors while running previous project which is using java16. Please help!